# Is there second season for Nisekoi as of this day April 21 2015?

Tags: nisekoi

I think im impatient. Im really inlove with Nisekoi, and I badly need to know when would it be release - the second season i mean. Last year December I found out that they will realease it on April this year and yet, I still don't know if it already is airing.

Comment: Um... Its out already...

Comment: really? wow thanks! can you refer me to any sites? thank you in advance :)

Comment: Well I don't stream so subgroups like HorribleSubs have them Subbed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2nd season of *Nisekoi* have already started airing since April 10, 2015. [In Japan, it is shown through the Tokyo MX, BS11, and MBS networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nisekoi). You can find a legal stream with English subtitles through [Crunchyroll](http://www.crunchyroll.com/nisekoi).